# Getting the top and height of text within formatted paragraphs

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am developing a PowerPoint add-in which inserts images between lines of text. In order to make room for the images, the add-in increases the spacing between the lines.
Unfortunately, after the line spacing has been increased there doesn't seem to be any way to get at the height and top of the actual text. .Lines(i)BoundTop and .Lines(i)BoundHeight gives dimensions for the line itself. Referring to individual characters within the line (using .Characters(j)) simply returns the same top and height as the line they are contained in - even though the actual height of a character may be much less than that of the line, and its top being below the top position for the line.

I have come up with a solution which involves creating a temporary test textbox and adding lines and paragraph formatting from the original textbox to observe what changes the formatting gives - and particularly using the fact that what spacing is applied depends on whether text is at the bottom, the top, or somewhere else in the textbox.

This seems a slighly inelegant solution - so I was wondering whether there is a better solution, or if I've missed something in the PowerPoint object model that would have given me this information.

This is the solution I have come up with so far:

```
Option Explicit

' lngLine - the index of the line to compute TextTop and TextHeight for.
' shTextBox - the text box containing the line.
' dblTextTop - returned value for the top of the text.
' dblTextHeight - returned value for the height of the text.
Public Sub TextPosition(ByVal lngLine As Long, _
                        ByRef shTextBox As Shape, _
                        ByRef dblTextTop As Double, _
                        ByRef dblTextHeight As Double)

  Dim shTestTextBox As Shape
  Dim dblMaxCharHeight As Double

  Dim trLine As TextRange
  Set trLine = shTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Lines(lngLine)

  ' The height of the derived textbox before manipulation:
  Dim dblBaseBoundHeight As Double

  Dim dblSpaceAfterAdded As Double
  Dim dblSpaceWithinAdded As Double
  Dim dblSpaceBeforeAdded As Double

  dblMaxCharHeight = MaxCharHeight(trLine)

  Dim lngSlideIndex As Long
  lngSlideIndex = shTextBox.Parent.SlideIndex

  With shTextBox.Parent.Parent.Slides(lngSlideIndex)

    ' Create a test textbox for the line.
    ' The height of this before and after paragraph formatting is used to
    ' compute where the text will be in relation to the bounding box of the
    ' line.
    Set shTestTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                                           Left:=shTextBox.Left, _
                                           Top:=trLine.BoundTop, _
                                           Width:=shTextBox.Width, _
                                           Height:=trLine.BoundHeight)

  End With

  Dim boolIsNewParagraph As Boolean
  With shTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To .Paragraphs.Count
      If .Paragraphs(i).Start = trLine.Start Then
        boolIsNewParagraph = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next i
  End With

  shTestTextBox.TextFrame.WordWrap = msoFalse

  With shTestTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange

    ' Lines which precede new paragraphs will have a return at the end of them
    ' (Chr(13)), leave this in for now.
    .Text = trLine.Text
    .Characters(1, .Characters.Count).Font.Size = dblMaxCharHeight

    ' Record the bound height of the text box before copying over the
    ' paragraph formatting.
    If .Lines.Count > 0 Then
      dblBaseBoundHeight = .Lines(1).BoundHeight
    Else
      dblBaseBoundHeight = .BoundHeight
    End If

    ' Space will get added if there is a return character Chr(13) - at the end
    ' of the line (i.e. preceding another paragraph).
    .ParagraphFormat.LineRuleAfter = trLine.ParagraphFormat.LineRuleAfter
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = trLine.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter

    If .Lines.Count > 0 Then
      dblSpaceAfterAdded = .Lines(1).BoundHeight - dblBaseBoundHeight
    Else
      dblSpaceAfterAdded = .BoundHeight - dblBaseBoundHeight
    End If

    ' If this is the first line of a paragraph, see what space will be added before:
    If boolIsNewParagraph Then
      .Text = Chr(13) & .Text
      If .Lines.Count > 1 Then
        .ParagraphFormat.LineRuleBefore = trLine.ParagraphFormat.LineRuleBefore
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = trLine.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore
        dblSpaceBeforeAdded = .Lines(2).BoundHeight - (dblBaseBoundHeight + dblSpaceAfterAdded)
      End If
    End If

    .Text = Replace(trLine.Text, Chr(13), "")
    ' The text is now (always) on the last (only) line of the test textbox, now
    ' add the within spacing and see what spacing that adds:
    .ParagraphFormat.LineRuleWithin = trLine.ParagraphFormat.LineRuleWithin
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin = trLine.ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin
    dblSpaceWithinAdded = trLine.BoundHeight - .BoundHeight

  End With

  dblTextHeight = dblBaseBoundHeight

  dblTextTop = (trLine.BoundTop + trLine.BoundHeight + dblSpaceBeforeAdded) - _
                 dblBaseBoundHeight - dblSpaceAfterAdded - dblSpaceWithinAdded


  shTestTextBox.Delete

End Sub

Public Function MaxCharHeight(ByRef trLine As TextRange) As Double

  Dim i As Long
  Dim dblMaxHeight As Double

  For i = 1 To trLine.Characters.Count
    If trLine.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size > dblMaxHeight Then
      dblMaxHeight = trLine.Characters(i, 1).Font.Size
    End If
  Next i

  MaxCharHeight = dblMaxHeight

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe you should try asking this Question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't track positioning at such a fine-grained level. If you could place each paragraph in a separate text box or shape, your task would be easier to solve.

Comment: I would have to agree with @JohnKorchok, Then you could set the height of each object in a more permanent position.

Comment: @JohnKorchok for my use case I would need to put each line (rather than each paragraph) in a textbox as I am aligning images to individual words. The text in the textboxes is entered by the user so I want to make the minimum amount of changes to what the user has entered as possible. I did consider dividing up the textbox originally, but I feel having the user ending up with multiple textboxes for the text they have entered could be confusing and messy - especially if they then want to add text, or delete some of it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use PowerPoint for this task? Other software, like Word, is better adapted to this kind of inline picture placement. Word picture captions do some of the same tasks, and are indexable.

Comment: Yes, though we will also be making a version of the add-in in Word. This is it: https://symboliser.commtap.org/ (without the word alignment feature as yet). Main users of the software are teachers adding support to their lesson materials for children with learning/communication difficulties. Teachers (in the UK anyway) very often use PowerPoint for their lessons. The same add-in also supports creation of communication boards/books to support those with severe communication disabilities - it's much easier to make these in PowerPoint.